# Instance member 'setViewTitle' cannot be used on type 'TViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have the following code:

```
Override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var contact: TContact? = TContactsManager.shared().getContactByJID(self.bareJid!.full())
    TViewController.setViewTitle(contact ? contactName.displayName() : THelpers.getContactMsisdnFromJid(self.bareJid?.full))
}
```

When I was trying to execute my application an error message appears:

```
 Instance member 'setViewTitle' cannot be used on type 'TViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
```

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: try this `self.setViewTitle(contact ? contactName.displayName() : THelpers.getContactMsisdnFromJid(self.bareJid?.full))`

Comment: How an instance method can be called without creating an instance /object?

Comment: You need to create a class method instead `class func setViewTitle(_ title: String)`